# Query to compare two tables with the same structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare two tables with the same exact structure (same column names).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_before;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_after;

CREATE TABLE my_before
(
     pk INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
     myvalue INT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE my_after
(
     pk INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
     myvalue INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_before (myvalue) VALUES (10), (NULL), (12), (NULL);
INSERT INTO my_after (myvalue) VALUES (10), (11), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (14);
```

I want to output the difference between my_before and my_after.

[image]

What would the query look like?

Comment: This is not a blogging platform

Comment: This is useful when monitoring regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this using `full join`, but the correct logic (to handle `NULL` values) is:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM my_before a FULL OUTER JOIN
     my_after b
     ON a.pk = b.pk
WHERE a.pk IS NULL OR
      b.pk IS NULL OR
      a.my_value <> b.my_value OR
      (a.my_value IS NULL AND b.my_value IS NOT NULL) OR
      (a.my_value IS NOT NULL AND b.my_value IS NULL);
```

Comment: is <> the same as != ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . More precisely, `!=` is the same as `<>`.  The latter was in SQL first.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM my_before AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN my_after AS b ON a.pk=b.pk
WHERE a.pk IS NULL OR b.pk IS NULL
 OR COALESCE(a.myvalue,0) != COALESCE(b.myvalue,0)
```

[image]

Without the COALESCE, the result would be completely different (and wrong)

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM my_before AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN my_after AS b ON a.pk=b.pk
    WHERE a.pk IS NULL OR b.pk IS NULL
     OR a.myvalue != b.myvalue
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is actually lacking, because if myvalue is NULL on one side and 0 on the other side, since COALESCE(NULL,0)=0 and COALESCE(0,0)=0. So this difference would be overlooked by the query with the COALESCE.

Answer (score 0):

Records missed in "after" table:

```
select * from my_before
except
select * from my_after
```

Records missed in "before" table:

```
select * from my_after
except
select * from my_before
```